# Correct way of creating and managing dependencies between concurrent futures in Python

Tags: python, concurrency, dependencies, future

Right now I'm on a journey exploring parallelism (both multiprocessing and multithreading). Futures seems to be a popular thing so I'm experimenting to figure out if I can create dependencies between futures and use them in my own application.

I will use the following code that I've written as an example:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import os

def dependent_future():
    def thread_fn(x, y):
        res = x + y
        return res

    def thread_fn_with_dep(xy_future, power):
        xy = xy_future.result()
        res = pow(xy, power)
        return res

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
        xy_future = executor.submit(thread_fn, 13, 34)
        xy_power_future = executor.submit(thread_fn_with_dep, xy_future, 2)


dependent_future()
```

I would like to know if this is the correct way to make one future dependent on another. From what I understand calling `result()` blocks the execution (here hopefully just of the thread executing `thread_fn_with_dep(...)`) so only after `thread_fn` has been completed `thread_fn_with_dep` will be executed. However the following other example I've come up with (represents a sum expression of a polynomial) doesn't work as expected:

```
def multidep_future():
    def polynom(fs):
        sum = 0
        for f in as_completed(fs):
            res, idx = f.result()
            print("[future_idx : " + str(idx) + "] : res = " + str(res) + ", sum_intermediate = " + str(sum) + "]")
            sum = sum + res

        return sum

    def mult(a_k, x, k):
        x_pow_res = pow(x, k)
        a_x_mult = a_k*x_pow_res
        print("a_" + str(k) + "*x^" + str(k) + " = " + str(a_k) + "*" + str(x) + "^" + str(k)
              + " = " + str(a_k) + "*" + str(x_pow_res)
              + " = " + str(a_x_mult))

        return pow(a_k*x, k), k

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
        x = 1
        futures = [
            executor.submit(mult, k, x, k)
            for k in range(5)
        ]

        poly = executor.submit(polynom, futures)

        print(poly.result())


multidep_future()
```

The output is

```
a_0*x^0 = 0*1^0 = 0*1 = 0
a_1*x^1 = 1*1^1 = 1*1 = 1
a_2*x^2 = 2*1^2 = 2*1 = 2
a_3*x^3 = 3*1^3 = 3*1 = 3
a_4*x^4 = 4*1^4 = 4*1 = 4
[future_idx : 2] : res = 4, sum_intermediate = 0]
[future_idx : 3] : res = 27, sum_intermediate = 4]
[future_idx : 0] : res = 1, sum_intermediate = 31]
[future_idx : 1] : res = 1, sum_intermediate = 32]
[future_idx : 4] : res = 256, sum_intermediate = 33]
289
```

What I am expecting is

```
a_0*x^0 = 0*1^0 = 0*1 = 0
a_1*x^1 = 1*1^1 = 1*1 = 1
a_2*x^2 = 2*1^2 = 2*1 = 2
a_3*x^3 = 3*1^3 = 3*1 = 3
a_4*x^4 = 4*1^4 = 4*1 = 4
[future_idx : 2] : res = 2, sum_intermediate = 3]
[future_idx : 3] : res = 3, sum_intermediate = 6]
[future_idx : 0] : res = 0, sum_intermediate = 0]
[future_idx : 1] : res = 1, sum_intermediate = 1]
[future_idx : 4] : res = 4, sum_intermediate = 10]
10
```

since (sorted)

```
  a_0*x^0 + a_1*x^1 + a_2*x^2 + a_3*x^3 + a_4*x^4
= 0*x^0 + 1*x^1 + 2*x^2 + 3*x^3 + 4*x^4
= 0*1^0 + 1*1^1 + 2*1^2 + 3*1^3 + 4*1^4
= 0*0 + 1*1 + 2*1 + 3*1 + 4*1
= 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
= 3 + 3 + 4
= 6 + 4
= 10
```

I'm clearly missing something here.

In addition I would like to know how to manage multiple dependencies especially if a more complex chain of tasks is present, where - due to failure of one task - only a subset of the remaining can be executed. This is more of a "what will happen to dependent tasks if a dependency task gets stuck or fails" question.

A more advanced example would be image processing. Usually the initial stage is converting the source image to one with a reduced colour space (e.g. grayscale aka gray monochrome). After that we can go one applying Gaussian to reduce the noise and then we can pass the result to various procedures such as opening/closing, edge detection, corner detection, feature detection, feature matching, writing some result to a file, sending the image data over a network etc. This introduces  multiple bottlenecks where several steps are in their nature parallel but depend on the same input. In such cases I would like to use futures given that what I've written as example code is how things are done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it will work. One downside of this approach is that you limit parallelization because a worker thread may wait for a future while another task would be available in the queue.

A better approach would be to only schedule the next task once the previous future becomes ready. You could use `future.add_done_callback` for this. However, programming this for complex work flows is tedious.

Overall you have to ask yourself if it is worth it in the first place. A complex dependency network between functions is hard to maintain and debug. Computations usually see better speedup with fork-join (e.g. parallel processing of a single image) due to better cache usage. I/O may even degrade if you overdo it with the parallelization.

All in all, it is often better to have a closer grip on the multithreading and use futures and thread pools only as one tool. For example I found it significantly better to use one thread pool for I/O and one for computation (if any).

Comment: See updated question.

I would also do just a couple of threads. But right now I am looking into different ways to do things in parallel. For example I have 3 processes - one that spawns two others, where one runs a GUI and the other does image processing. The image processing process contains a single thread to poll for incoming images, that are loaded by the GUI process. I would like to distribute the load related to different processing task along multiple threads and each will then put its result into a `multiprocessing.Queue` for the GUI to visualize.